# Plotext and Curses - windows

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, utf-8, python-curses

Needed help with this code:

```py
import plotext as plt
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io
import curses
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
code = locale.getpreferredencoding()

PlotFile = io.StringIO()

with redirect_stdout(PlotFile):
    y = plt.sin() # sinusoidal signal 
    plt.scatter(y, marker='dot', )
    plt.title("Scatter Plot")
    plt.plot_size(10, 10)
    plt.show()
PlotFile.seek(0)
w = PlotFile.readlines()
allchar = []
vischar = []
dechar = []
bychar = []
def main (stdscr):
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()
    k = 0
    for i in w:
        for c in i:
            if ord(c) not in allchar:
                allchar.append(ord(c))
                vischar.append(c)
                dechar.append(c.encode('utf-8'))
                bychar.append(bytes(dechar[-1]))
            stdscr.addstr(chr(ord(c)).encode('utf-8'))
        print(i)
        k += 1
   stdscr.refresh()
   curses.napms(3000)

curses.wrapper(main)


print(allchar)
print(vischar)
print(dechar)
print(bychar)
```

Using VScode on Windows python 3.9 and wincurses. While on ordinary terminal plotext working fine, in curses displaying odd characters like [[m , [[107m and others. Tried encoding and uft mess, still can't figure out how to manage this problem. As I already figured out curses use uft-8 by default, while python strings are encoded in utf-16, so conversion must be done. When tried to print each character one by one from `allchar` list all character displayed. But I noticed, that there is `[` character printed in curses, which is not in original plotext output. I think it is unicode problem somewhere  in middle, but still can't find. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the example does not run on my machine, but I can tell you that `plotext` outputs `[` inside the ansi code of the colored plot.
Here is, for example, the string `"plotext"` colored red:

```
'\x1b[38;5;1mplotext\x1b[0m'
```

If undesired, try the `clear_color()` method to remove colors and so the undesired ansi codes. Good luck.